# How to retrieve the entire list just by inputting one element from that list?

Tags: python, list

When I type in the Number corresponding to the person, things such as name and birthday should also appear

```
employInfo=[1,'De Leon','7/19/2001',
           2,'Fabian','6/6/1999'
           3,'Deseo','12/25/1998']
> output should be like:
Enter No.: 3
Employee with this No. is Deseo and his birthday is 12/25/1998.
```

I really don't know what i'm supposed to be doing here.

Comment: I don't really know either.  Type in where?  How?  What have you tried?

Comment: is it always follow `id`,`name`,`dob`?

Answer (score 0):

A list is the wrong data structure here, and you should be using a dictionary:

```
d = {1: ['De Leon', '7/19/2001'],
     2: ['Fabian', '6/6/1999'],
     3: ['Deseo', '12/25/1998']}

inp = 3
name = d[inp][0]
birthday = d[inp][1]
output = f"Employee with this No. is {name} and his birthday is {birthday}."
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
Employee with this No. is Deseo and his birthday is 12/25/1998.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class "Employee" and use a dictionary instead of the list:

```
employInfo =
{
    "1": employee1,
    "2": employee2
}
```

Then you can access each employee by its id. And you can use class methods to get employee data.

Answer (score 0):

```
employInfo = [1, 'De Leon', '7/19/2001',
              2, 'Fabien', '6/6/1999',
              3, 'Dereck', '12/25/1998']

usr_input = int(input("Enter No.: "))
num = usr_input - 1
name = 2 * usr_input + num - 1
date = usr_input * 3 - 1

sentence = "Employee with this No. is " + 
employInfo[name] + " and his birthday is " + 
employInfo[date]

print(sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unusual for a modern process/program to use this kind of data-structure where everything is packed into a single list, with different data-attributes occupying fixed positions in a repeating pattern, but in the old days, this was kind of how lots of fixed-width byte-encoded "random access" data files used to be.

The trick is to find a mapping from list to attribute type - so in your case,

```
employInfo=[1,'De Leon','7/19/2001',
           2,'Fabian','6/6/1999'
           3,'Deseo','12/25/1998']
```

The pattern is Number[0], Name[1], Date[2] and if you were to imagine this list extending on forever, you could predict that each record (starting at record 0) will contain the following positions.

```
Record n: Number = n*3, Name = (n*3)+1, Date = (n*3)+2
```

Going in reverse, if you find a match in the list at position m, then you can determine the record from which m is drawn using the inverse formulas:

```
Match m: Record n = int(m/3)
```

Give these two sets of formula, you can have one function that will return the record given a match at position m.

```
def get_content(m, data):
    n = int(m/3)
    number = data[(n*3)]
    name = data[(n*3)+1]
    date = data[(n*3)+2]
    return number, name, date
```

Next you need a method for searching your data - that could be something simple like:

```
def get_match_at(search, data):
    m= data.index(search)
    return m
```

And finally, now you can retrieve any record, you want to format it according to some stated requirement:

```
def format_record(record):
    number, name, date = record
    return f"Employee number {number} is called {name} and their birthday is {date}."
```

So now, you can run those functions independently:

```
get_match_at(3,employInfo)

> 6
```

To get the position of a match.

```
get_content(6, employInfo)

> (3, 'Deseo', '12/25/1998')
```

To get the record found given the match was found at position 6.

And finally, you can format that record using:

```
format_record((3, 'Deseo', '12/25/1998'))
```

To return:

```
> 'Employee number 3 is called Deseo and their birthday is 12/25/1998.'
```

String that all together into a single call:

```
format_record(get_content(get_match_at(3,employInfo),employInfo))

> 'Employee number 3 is called Deseo and their birthday is 12/25/1998.'
```

And you've got a relatively generalised search pipeline.

I say generalised, because it should work for matches on name or date as well as number.

e.g. Perform a search by name, rather than by id:

```
format_record(get_content(get_match_at('Deseo',employInfo),employInfo))

> 'Employee number 3 is called Deseo and their birthday is 12/25/1998.'
```

It's just a case of breaking down the process into discrete steps that build on top of one another.